# What is the hydrostatic pressure within the lattice volumes of a sponge relative to the external hydrostatic pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A sponge is a crosslinked array of elastic polymers. If water flows into the sponge the polymers are stretched and that should raise the aqueous hydrostatic pressure within the sponge. Is that true? I can't find a paper on that idea.

Comment: Why would water flowing into a sponge necessarily cause its polymers to stretch?

Answer (score 0):

When a block of reticulated sponge takes up water, the inter-pore webs to not stretch much and unless the sponge was in a compressed and dry state when first wetted, its dimensions will change little as it becomes saturated. Hydrostatically, you can model a block of sponge as a dense bundle of vertically-disposed capillary tubes in which the tube diameter approximates the nominal pore size of the sponge, and the rise height of liquid in the sponge at equilibrium is approximated by what the rise height due to capillary draw in the tube bundle would be, assuming the same wetting characteristics of the tubes and the sponge material.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking that the stretched polymers (assuming they do stretch upon absorbing water) will press on the absorbed mass of water and therefore pressurise it. However if the free surface of water is exposed to atmosphere. which is the case for water absorbed by sponge, the pressure will be atmospheric at its free surface, and pressure further down will then be determined by the usual hydrostatic formula. In fact the stretching of elastic polymers would be in response to the hydrostatic pressure inside the water body and not the other way round.

All of this assumes that gravity has significant effect on flow of liquid into sponge, which is likely not true. But you can think of a different but related scenario. Suppose you fill a balloon with water; is water pressure inside the balloon higher because the balloon is stretched due to weight of water? The answer is No, because if it were higher then the hydrostatic pressure due to gravity couldn't balance it and therefore water inside the balloon would move upward to be ejected out of the balloon. It is the balloon which deforms in response to hydrostatic pressure of water (until it reaches an equilibrium configuration) and not the other way round.

Comment: For the polymers to encase more water the lattice has to expand and for that to happen in a cross lined lattice you have to stretch the polymers so the water encased by the polymers will have to have higher pressure, otherwise why should water inflow not explode the sponge?  These questions do not involve gravity since sponges can work in zero gravity.

Comment: @fredericksachs Agreed, the lattice has to expand. However if "...water encased by the polymers will have to have higher pressure..."compared to hydrostatic value then what counterbalances the extra pressure to keep the water inside rather than be ejected out of the sponge?